# Bash: No such file or directory when running shell comands with node.js spawn on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, bash

I wrote the following web server in node.js using express and hbs that can run shell files, but I keep getting the  following error when I type this url into a web browser

> linux username here is replaced with my linux username

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/run?file="/home/linux username here/nasServer/GameServers/minecraft/1.16.2 server/run.sh"
```

```
stderr: bash: <path to .sh file here>: No such file or directory.
child process exited with code 127.
```

Contents of nodejs file:

```js
const express = require('express')
const hbs = require('hbs')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
// Set up handlebars engine
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.get('/run', (req, res) => {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    let callback = ""
    ls = spawn("bash", [req.query.file])

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
    });

    ls.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString());
    });
    res.send({
        out: callback
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

This is the contents of run.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx5G -jar /home/linux username here/nasServer/GameServers/minecraft/1.16.2\ server/spigot-1.16.2.jar nogui
```

Comment: Does it actually report the correct (and I mean *exactly* correct) path in the error message? BTW, you should be aware that this service is hopelessly insecure.

Comment: The error message has exactly the same path. I know that this is insecure but I am using it on my own private network with no access to the outside world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello, I don't know why I decided to try to fix this since I know just a little bit about coding (only scripting actually lol) and nothing about nodeJs but I got fun testing your app with the help of my friend google !

First of all, since i dont have your minecraft files (jar etc.), I just writed a little script "test.sh", that will just echo your command:

```
❯ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "java -Xmx5G -jar /home/linux username here/nasServer/GameServers/minecraft/1.16.2\ server/spigot-1.16.2.jar nogui"
```

second of all after like 2hours of training, modifying, testing by adding/deleting stuff into your app to understand how it works, I finally came back to your original app when i find that it works with this:

```
http://localhost:3000/run?file=test.sh
```

here is the browser output (as expected):

```
{"out":""}
```

here is the console output:

```
❯  node 71963151.js
App listening on port 3000
stdout: java -Xmx5G -jar /home/linux username here/nasServer/GameServers/minecraft/1.16.2\ server/spigot-1.16.2.jar nogui

child process exited with code 0
```

The fact is that when we remove the double quotes from the query it works fine, but when I add back the double quotes like you are trying to do:

```
http://localhost:3000/run?file="test.sh"
```

here is the browser output (as expected):

```
{"out":""}
```

but here is the consol output:

```
❯  node 71963151.js
App listening on port 3000
stderr: bash: "test.sh": No such file or directory

child process exited with code 127
```

So, to conclude, instead of trying to run this on your browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/run?file="/home/<linux username here>/nasServer/GameServers/minecraft/<1.16.2 server>/run.sh"
```

try this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/run?file=/home/<linux username here>/nasServer/GameServers/minecraft/<1.16.2 server>/run.sh
```

A lot of documentation helped me out to understand the way nodejs works, I loved doing this :p thank you, You made me want to code!
bguess.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by replacing all the windows line endings with Unix line endings, then bash found the .sh file.